# how to get warned when there is a name collision in jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have the following xml:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter >value1</param>
    <parameter >value2</param>
</parameters>
```

with the following class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Parameters {
    @XmlElement public String parameter;
}
```

How can I get warned (exception?) of the duplicate values when unmarshaling the xml to object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a schema a make a schema validation. If your schema permits duplicates then maybe you should switch from `String` to a `Collection` type.

If you don't have a schema, you could use [schemagen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/schemagen.html) tool to generate it from your java classes.
You could even generate a schema at [runtime](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema), maybe cache it together with the `JaxbContext` and then use it for validation.

Comment: can I avoid duplicates only using the java class?

Comment: I updated the answer, I don't think you can do this type of validation another way.

Comment: +1 - The following article demonstrates how to leverage schema validation during an unmarshal operation:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html